# How to persist the image selected from gallery on the layout even if we returned to the activity again?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I have relative layout in which i have an image view.I am selecting an image for it from the gallery.I used intent to go to other activity.When i returned to the first activity,my image from the gallery was not there.I want to display the gallery image on the screen even if i returned to the activity.please help me.

Comment: add the code that you have tried to achieve your requirement with

Comment: you will have to draw text on the canvas that has the bitmap as the background or drawable

Comment: Actually that is not my problem.I have modified my problem now. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap represent any view by using pixel.I don't understand Why did you use it for textview.
You can use textview inside relative layout and set the text which is coming from intent by using ".setText()" method.

Comment: I want to display text on the bitmap.that is why i used